# adding vlues in a table and displaying highest vsalue

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
 account
 account_number     balance
 -------------      --------

 depositor
 account_number     name
 --------------     ----
```

What need to do is display the name and  value of the highest account.  I used the following to statement to get all the names and account values in one place.

> 

```
select ACCount.balance, depositor.customer_name
2  from account
3  inner join depositor
4  on account.account_number = depositor.account_number;

BALANCE CUSTOMER_NAME
---------- ---------------
   500 customer1
   400 customer1
   500 customer2
   900 customer2
  6250 customer2
  7500 customer3
100000 customer4
```

But i am stuck on getting the SUM(balance) as well just displaying the highest account.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `group by`, `order by` and `limit`:

```
select sum(a.balance) as totalbalance, d.customer_name
from account a inner join
     depositor d
     on a.account_number = d.account_number
group by d.customer_name
order by totalbalance desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use Limit 1,2,3 if you need top 1,2,3 etc. Like (**limit 1**)

```
select sum(account.balance) as totalbalance, depositor.customer_name from account inner join depositor on account.account_number = depositor.account_number group by depositor.customer_name order by totalbalance desc;
```